# Why do these perfect similar `Matrix` produce difference result when applied to `Canvas.setMatrix()`?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to convert an `ImageView` to bitmap with transformation applied, such as `rotation` , `rotationX` ,`rotationY` , `scaleX` etc. But i've found strange behavior of these similar `matrix`s (`testMatrix` and `binding.ivMainImage.matrix`)

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val testMatrix = Matrix()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.ivMainImage.rotation = 23f
        binding.ivMainImage.scaleX = 0.5f
        binding.ivMainImage.scaleY = 0.6f
        binding.ivMainImage.rotationY = 20f

        // set testMatrix values
        testMatrix.set(binding.ivMainImage.matrix)
        Log.i("DEBUG", "matrix:testMatrix  :${testMatrix.toShortString()}")
        Log.i("DEBUG", "matrix:ivMainImage :${binding.ivMainImage.matrix.toShortString()}")

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            val result1 = binding.ivMainImage.drawToBitmap(binding.ivMainImage.matrix)
            binding.ivResult1.setImageBitmap(result1)

            val result2 = binding.ivMainImage.drawToBitmap(testMatrix)
            binding.ivResult2.setImageBitmap(result2)
        }
    }

    private fun View.drawToBitmap(
        matrix: Matrix,
        config: Bitmap.Config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    ): Bitmap{
        if (!ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this)) {
            throw IllegalStateException("View needs to be laid out before calling drawToBitmap()")
        }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config).applyCanvas {
            translate(-scrollX.toFloat(), -scrollY.toFloat())
            setMatrix(matrix)
            this@drawToBitmap.draw(this)
        }
    }
}
```

**Log**

```
04-16 23:03:56.004 10466-10466/com.example.myapplication I/DEBUG: matrix:testMatrix  :[0.4324958, -0.2203003, 0.0][0.19536556, 0.55230296, 0.0][2.7329096E-4, -1.3920615E-4, 1.0]
04-16 23:03:56.005 10466-10466/com.example.myapplication I/DEBUG: matrix:ivMainImage :[0.4324958, -0.2203003, 0.0][0.19536556, 0.55230296, 0.0][2.7329096E-4, -1.3920615E-4, 1.0]
```

as you can see above , the `matrix`s values are perfectly similar , but those are produce different result, see below

[image]

**Xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>

    //TextView

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMainImage"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/test_image_1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvMainImage" />

    //TextView

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivResult1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivMainImage" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivResult2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivMainImage" />

    
    //Button
    //GuideLine

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The **`Result 1`** is correct, my question is why do these `matrix`s (**`testMatrix`** and **`binding.ivMainImage.matrix`**) produce different result even if the values are perfectly similar ??

Comment: Flip your test round, instead of doing `testMatrix.set(binding.ivMainImage.matrix)` try `binding.ivMainImage.matrix.set(testMatix)`. This will prove if you are right or wrong about them being "identical".

Comment: @Blundell But the `testMatrix` is an identity matrix , if i set the `ivMainImage.martix` to `testMatrix` , isn't that mean i reset the transformation (rotation , scale etc) ??

Comment: What I meant was, you are thinking they re equal matrices but one is created from the other, which perhaps can be why they are unequal.

Comment: @Blundell two matrices are equal if Each matrix has the same number of rows & column , and Corresponding elements within each matrix are equal. and if you take a look at `Matrix()` documentation and scroll down to the `equal` method , it is also said `Returns true iff obj is a Matrix and its values equal our values`., so based on these rules `testMatrix`  and `ivMainImage.martix` are actually equal.